# sudo nopassword but prompt

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

I want to create a bash tool to help backing up my system, but I plan for it to be modular so I can share it out.

I plan to `source` scripts that a user can download into a "plugin" folder and I expect that some of these scripts will use sudo. Now I know that using sudo a bunch of times means for most users that the password does not need to be entered each time, but I want to be extra vigilant and at least get confirmation between each sudo attempt. This means that although I don't necessarily need the user to type their password for every sudo command, I do want them to see, vet, and allow every sudo command by hand.

Is there any way to do this? eg:

```bsh
$ script.sh
doing stuff...
about to run `sudo kill -9 938` do you want to proceed? [y/N] y
password: **********
doing other stuff...
about to run `sudo rm -rf ~/.cache` do you want to proceed? [y/N] y
about to run `sudo rm -rf /` do you want to proceed? [y/N] n
skipping.
etc...
finished.
$ _
```

EDIT: I think I have not done a good job explaining the problem. I wish to create some sort of subshell where the word `sudo` is a custom function and then run a script within it. In that custom function, I would `echo` to make sure all sudo commands are logged out before actually running the original command.

Comment: The simplest option would be to use sudo's exisiting `-k` and/or `-K` to revoke cached credentials. Otherwise, sure you can write a script to ask questions and respond to answers (using the shell's `read` and `case` constructs for example)

Answer (score 0):

We can run the command without root privileges by adding those commands to sudoers file under NOPASSWD

Try the following command.

```
 sudo visudo
```

Go to the last line, and type the following command.

```
user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/bash *.sh
```

And then save the file. Login to the user and try to run the script by using sudo., For an example

```
sudo bash script.sh
```